# php mysql query latitude longitude syntax

Tags: php, mysql, sql, latitude-longitude

I'm setting up a lat/long search for nearby cities. It is based on Google's [example](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch.html).

**Code**

```
    $query = sprintf("SELECT Zip, City, State, Lat, Long, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Zips HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 18",
      mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
      mysql_real_escape_string($lng),
      mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
      mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
    $result = mysql_query($query, $dbConn);
```

**Error**

```
Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Long, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('37') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians' at line 1 Whole query: SELECT Zip, City, State, Lat, Long, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('37') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('-122') ) + sin( radians('37') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Zips HAVING distance < '50' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 18
```

**Update -- Working Example**

```
    $query = sprintf("SELECT `Zip`, `City`, `State`, `Lat`, `Long`, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( `Lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `Long` ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( `Lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Zips HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 18",
      mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
      mysql_real_escape_string($lng),
      mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
      mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
    $result = mysql_query($query, $dbConn);
```

Comment: Insert die( $query ); between these 2 lines. If this doesn't help you figure it out post that.

Comment: SELECT Zip, City, State, Lat, Long, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('37') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('-122') ) + sin( radians('37') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Zips HAVING distance < '50' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 18

Comment: I think the other guy who deleted his post was still right. I think you want WHERE instead of HAVING

Comment: It's the same error with it in or out

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Long` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html).

Escape your column names so MySQL doesn't think you're trying to cast a comma:

```
SELECT `Zip`, `City`, `State`, `Lat`, `Long`, 
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( `Lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `Long` ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( `Lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM Zips 
HAVING distance < '%s' 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 18
```

Comment: Ha, I checked Lat and not Long, Duh. Note that you just enclose them in backticks (`)- stackoverflow is changing in your response

Comment: Invalid query: Unknown column 'lng' in 'field list' Whole query: SELECT `Zip`, `City`, `State`, `Lat`, `Long`, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('37') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians('-122') ) + sin( radians('37') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Zips WHERE distance < '50' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 18

Comment: I fixed the query display, initially I didn't format the markdown correctly.

Comment: Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'long ) - radians('-122') ) + sin( radians('37') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS' at line 1 Whole query: SELECT `Zip`, `City`, `State`, `Lat`, `Long`, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('37') ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( long ) - radians('-122') ) + sin( radians('37') ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Zips WHERE distance < '50' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 18

Comment: You need to enclose long in backticks(`) in all places. c'mon man

Comment: Invalid query: Unknown column 'distance' in 'where clause' Whole query: SELECT `Zip`, `City`, `State`, `Lat`, `Long`, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('37') ) * cos( radians( `Lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `Long` ) - radians('-122') ) + sin( radians('37') ) * sin( radians( `Lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Zips WHERE distance < '50' ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 18

Answer (score 4):

**Long** is a mysql keyword. You should either rename the column or enclose the column name in back ticks.